# Python pandas, read_fwf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datatable, fixed-width

I'm trying to read a table from a text file (or `StringIO`) into `pandas`. To accomplish this, I use `pandas.read_fwf`.

However, I'm facing problems with the automatic column width detection.
In my case it works properly for columns 1-3 but not for column 4, which contains informal text of undefined width.

The detection works good for the first three columns, because their width can properly determined from the headers. The 4th column start can also be determined properly, as it is aligned with the corresponding header.

However, pandas refuses to put all remaining text into the 4th column.
It either creates several `Unnamed: X` columns with each word of the informal text in one column or it creates one named column which contains only the first word of the informal text.

Here is the column format:

```
CL              NAME          STATE        INFO
some category   some_name     some_state   some informal info text
...
```

I'd like to achieve that all categories are put in column 1, all names in column two, all states in column three and all infos in column 4.

The two options I tried were:

- ```
  x1 = pandas.read_fwf(infile, infer_nrows=1)
  ```

  -> Results in a `INFO` column containing only the first word of the info text.

  ```
                         CL          NAME  ... Unnamed: 5 Unnamed: 6
  0          some category     some_name  ...        NaN        NaN
  ```
- ```
  x2 = pandas.read_fwf(infile)
  ```

  -> Results in several unnamed columns each containing one word of the info text.

  ```
      CL             NAME             STATE     INFO
  0   some      some_name        some_state     some
  ```

Comment: Why use `infer_nrows=1`? Does that potentially tell pandas that your final column is fixed width 4 characters?  I would use the default 100 or explicitly set the column widths using `colspecs`.

Comment: It would be possible to infer the column width of the first three columns from the header and set the 4th column to a large column width. That's what I tried to do using `infer_nrows=1` in order to prevent the parser from detecting spare columns.

Comment: That's not really how `read_fwf` works; the first line doesn't have sufficient width for the last column; therefore you see a lot of unnamed columns latter on. Either remove that param, or specify `colspecs` as @JonSG suggests. You can probably also use `read_csv` with `sep='\s{2,}`.

Comment: Maybe use the `colspecs` parameter: Instead of `widths`, you can use it to specify the start and end positions of each column.

Comment: I found a complicated solution determining the colwidths of my own iterating over `re.finditer(r"\S+", headers)` and calculating the differences of the start positions of subsequent matches. `pandas` does not help, here. I can then pass the determined column widths to `read_fwf`.